# HTTP code 301: why and how to allows changing the request method from POST to GET

Tags: http, redirect

I'm writing a http handling library and now dealing with reduction. I'm a little confused about the response code `301`, it said that `when 301 happens, it is allowed to change the request method from POST to GET`.

Since POST method contains bodies while GET doesn't, how could I resend the original POST request to the new location with GET, without losing bodies?

And why the protocol allow this changing, any particularly reason?

Comment: A 301 is indicative of a permanent change of one URL to another.  It's simply a way of informing the caller that the destination address should be permanently changed to somewhere else.  Where the new destination accepts `POST` or `GET` is really up to them, but if the previously destination accepted a `POST` then the replacement destination _should_ too.  Complex payloads cannot be included in the `GET` request as you already are aware.

Comment: @psionic12 — Answering that bit likely requires guessing what the people who wrote the spec decades ago were thinking, which isn't really possible.

Comment: So in practice, is it okay that my lib just re-send the request as what ever it is, not consider the change thing?

Comment: @psionic12 I would suggest that if the original end-point accepted `POST` and returns a `301`, that the new end-point _should_ also accept `POST`.  It would be better if they were returning a `308` though which doesn't permit the method to change

Comment: By the way the fact that GET request cannot contain a body is not clearly stated in RFC, and some http servers support bodies in GET requests.

Comment: @regilero Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/2169762.  You can send a payload with the `GET` but it may be discarded or ignored by the server before delivered to the end software